# Parameter deletion in a keyword (.resource file) from a test file (.robot file) - Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

good afternoon.

I have the following question:
I can delete a parameter contained in a keyword in .resource file, but doing this action in my test .robot file?
I tried with the Remove From Dictionary, but this keyword works only when i'm the same file...

Example:

**.resource File**

```
*** Keywords ***

Start
    &{BODY}      Create Dictionary
    ...    userSystemName=${USER_SYSTEM_NAME}
    ...    ispbPsp=${ISPB_PSP}
    ...    isSystem=${TRUE}

Set Suite Variable    &{BODY}
```

**.robot File**

```
*** Test Cases ***

    Test Start
          Start
```

In my test case I want to exclude the "ispbPsp" param before send the request (RequestLibrary).

I can this?

How?

Thanks very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword [Remove From Dictionary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/4.1.3/libraries/Collections.html#Remove%20From%20Dictionary) in a copy of the variable

```
*** Test Cases ***

Test Start
  Start
  ${bodycopy}=  ${BODY}
  Remove From Dictionary  ${bodycopy}  ispbPsp
  Do Something With  ${bodycopy}
```

Comment: Very thanks, danilopopeye! Resolved!